# Converting nested XML to non-nested numbered HTML list XSLT 3

Tags: html, xml, xslt-3.0

I have nested `levelledPara`s in my XML that I would like to convert to a non-nested numbered list in HTML. It doesn't matter how they are arranged (ul, grid, flexbox, etc.) as long as they are side-by-side and the numbers column is 21mm wide. I can't figure out how to do this without nesting the HTML, but I'm assuming I need an intermediate step like saving the first pass to a variable and then outputting the contents of the variable.

Input:

```
<dmodule>
    <content>
        <crew>
            <descrCrew>
                <levelledPara>
                    <title>Introduction</title>
                    <para>Data about the bicycle and its control system is given in this document.
                        This data will help you operate the bicycle.</para>
                </levelledPara>
                <levelledPara>
                    <levelledPara>
                        <title>Controls</title>
                        <para>Data about the controls that follow is given in this document:
                            
                        </para>
                        <levelledPara>
                            <title>Level 3</title>
                            <para>Some text to put here for level 3 levelledpara.</para>
                        </levelledPara>
                    </levelledPara>
                    <levelledPara id="par-0001">
                        <title>Steering</title>
                        <para>The handlebars are used to steer the bike. They are at the front of
                            the bicycle. You hold one of the handlebar grips with each hand and move
                            the handle bar to change the direction of the bike.</para>
                    </levelledPara>
                    <levelledPara id="par-0002">
                        <title>Shifters</title>
                        <para>The gears control the ratio of pedal rotation to wheel rotation. You
                            can change this with the shifters. The shifters are on the handlebar.</para>
                        <para>A description of the two shifters follows.</para>
                    </levelledPara>
                </levelledPara>
            </descrCrew>
        </crew>
    </content>
</dmodule>
```

desired output:

```
<div>
     <div style="display: flex;">
        <div style="width:21mm;">1</div>
        <div><span class="Sidehead1">Introduction</span><p>Data about the bicycle and its control system is given in this document.
              This data will help you operate the bicycle.</p>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div style="display: flex;">
        <div style="width:21mm;">2.1</div>
        <div><span class="Sidehead2">Controls</span><p>Data about the controls that follow is given in this document.</p>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div style="display: flex;">
        <div style="width:21mm;">2.1.1</div>
        <div><span class="Sidehead3">Level 3</span><p>Some text to put here for level 3 levelledpara.</p>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div style="display: flex;">
        <div style="width:21mm;">2.2</div>
        <div><span class="Sidehead2">Steering</span><p>The handlebars are used to steer the bike. They are at the front of
           the bicycle. You hold one of the handlebar grips with each hand and move
           the handle bar to change the direction of the bike.</p>
        </div>
     </div>
           
     <div style="display: flex;">
        <div style="width:21mm;">2.3</div>
        <div><span class="Sidehead2">Shifters</span><p>The gears control the ratio of pedal rotation to wheel rotation. You
              can change this with the shifters. The shifters are on the handlebar.</p>
           <p>A description of the two shifters follows.</p>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

actual output:

```
<div style="display: flex;">
         <div style="width:21mm;">1</div>
         <div><span class="Sidehead1">Introduction</span><p>Data about the bicycle and its control system is given in this document.
               This data will help you operate the bicycle.</p>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div style="display: flex;">
         <div style="width:21mm;"></div>
         <div>
            <div style="display: flex;">
               <div style="width:21mm;">2.1</div>
               <div><span class="Sidehead2">Controls</span><p>Data about the controls that follow is given in this document:
                     
                     </p>
                  <div style="display: flex;">
                     <div style="width:21mm;">2.1.1</div>
                     <div><span class="Sidehead3">Level 3</span><p>Some text to put here for level 3 levelledpara.</p>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div style="display: flex;">
               <div style="width:21mm;">2.2</div>
               <div><span class="Sidehead2">Steering</span><p>The handlebars are used to steer the bike. They are at the front of
                     the bicycle. You hold one of the handlebar grips with each hand and move
                     the handle bar to change the direction of the bike.</p>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div style="display: flex;">
               <div style="width:21mm;">2.3</div>
               <div><span class="Sidehead2">Shifters</span><p>The gears control the ratio of pedal rotation to wheel rotation. You
                     can change this with the shifters. The shifters are on the handlebar.</p>
                  <p>A description of the two shifters follows.</p>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
</div>
```

xslt:

```
<xsl:template match="levelledPara[title]">
            <div style="display: flex;">
                <div style="width:21mm;">
                    <xsl:number count="levelledPara" from="content" level="multiple" format="1.1.1.1.1"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </div>
            </div>
</xsl:template>
        
<xsl:template match="levelledPara">
            <div style="display: flex;">  
                <!-- suppress numbering if parent levelledPara doesn't have a title -->
                <div style="width:21mm;">
                    <xsl:if test="not(levelledPara/title)">
                        <xsl:number count="levelledPara" from="content" level="multiple" format="1.1.1.1.1"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </div>
            </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think that

```
  <xsl:template match="descrCrew">
    <div>
      <xsl:apply-templates select=".//levelledPara[title]"/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="levelledPara">
            <div style="display: flex;">
                <div style="width:21mm;">
                    <xsl:number count="levelledPara" from="content" level="multiple" format="1.1.1.1.1"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="* except levelledPara"/>
                </div>
            </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="levelledPara/title">
    <span class="Sidehead2">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </span>
  </xsl:template>
```

creates the flat `div` structure.

In terms of the CSS layout width of the number, at least with Chrome I get a better result using e.g. `<div style="min-width:21mm;">` instead of `<div style="width:21mm;">`.